# filter query equals to given lucene query

Tags: solr, lucene

My Lucene query is : **+((+MinimumPrice:[1000.0 TO 10000.0]) | (+MaximumPrice:[1000.0 TO 10000.0]))**

its equivalent filter query: **fq=MinimumPrice:[1000 TO 10000] OR MaximumPrice:[1000 TO 10000]**

But I want it in the form of **fq=MinimumPrice:*Parameters*&fq=MaximumPrice:*Parameters***

You can replace Parameters by any kind of range, but results count should be equal.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that your problem is that, the result count is not equal when you use it in the form of this:

```
fq=MinimumPrice:Parameters&fq=MaximumPrice:Parameters
```

It is also to be expected, because the default relation between two fq (filter queries) is an **AND** relation, so

```
fq=MinimumPrice:Parameters&fq=MaximumPrice:Parameters
```

actuall translates into

```
fq=MinimumPrice:[1000 TO 10000] AND MaximumPrice:[1000 TO 10000]
```

Comment: thanks for your kind information, but this is not the solution of my problem.